# Proper mercurial workflow for maintain two separate configurations with shared state

Tags: mercurial

I'm using hg to manage some config files, and I'm looking for some suggestions for workflows.

There are two possible configurations for the release version, say A and B. Most of the settings are the same between the two, but there are a couple of differences. I would like to use the repository so these criteria are satisfied:

- All history is backed up (no random patches floating around)
- Changing a file used in both Config A and Config B can be done in only one place (I'd prefer not to have to keep two separate sets of files in sync) and with minimal post-processing (see the `hg graft` idea below)
- It is possible to easily switch between Config A and Config B when deploying (presumably with something like `hg update config-a` or `hg update config-b`)

A couple of ideas I have had and explored to various degrees:

- Two separate repositories or branches

This works fine, but means that changes have to be synchronized in two independent places, which is annoying and error-prone.

- One main branch for Config A, and patches handled by mq to switch to B

I haven't actually used `mq` and the internet seems to be suggesting it's almost deprecated and shouldn't be used because it has issues with backing up changes. It may be the case that this is a legitimate use of it, but I'd like confirmation from its users before committing to this path.

- One main branch for Config A, one random changeset somewhere in history describing how to switch from A to B, and use `hg graft` to create a second head for Config B whenever the common config files are edited.

This approach seems plausible, but (1) history will be littered with extra heads whenever `hg graft` was applied (I can't really strip them because they'll be published to a server for redistribution), (2) it requires an extra step whenever editing common files, (3) I haven't figured out how to create a new branch when `hg graft`-ing, so I'll have to remember to reupdate to the `config-a` tip when making common changes, and (4) if the changeset to switch from A to B is modified or gains additional steps, it's not clear to me how to nicely keep track of "this sequence of changesets that moves A to B but doesn't actually have a head" (that phrasing actually sounds a lot like `mq`).

- Any other suggestions?

(Please use the criteria above to keep answers fact-based rather than primarily opinion-based [yes, added so it won't be closed :-) ] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use two named branches in a single repository and it works ok. I always do the common changes in the same branch (say "config-a") and then merge to the other branch. It involves a bit of post-processing since you always have to merge the common stuff, but it doesn't take that much time once you get used to it, e.g.:

```
hg update config-a
<change some files>
hg commit -m "Some common config change"
hg update config-b
hg merge config-a
hg commit -m "Merge from config-a"
```

Merges are always done from a to b, so changes specific to b will never make it in a. However, when making a change specific to a, you must remember to revert it when merging to b (aka "dummy merge" it), e.g.:

```
...
hg update config-b
hg merge config-a
hg revert --all --rev .
hg commit -m "Dummy merge from config-a"
```

Instead of doing a `hg revert` you could also manually edit the files to adapt the change to config-b.

Edit: According to the [Mercurial doc](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge), a safe way to do a dummy merge - and prevent any external merge tool to mess with it in case of conflicts - is to do this:

```
hg -y merge --tool=internal:fail config-a
hg revert --all --rev .
hg resolve -a -m
```

Comment: That looks pretty reasonable -- will give it a try. FWIW I think you can do `hg merge config-a -t "internal:local"` in place of the `hg revert` step.

Comment: This can work under some circumstances, but I don't think it is a safe way to do a dummy merge. See the explanation here: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge